Lost git commits but can see them in PowerShell history
Was working on some project at last Friday, made some commits before and after lunch.
Today(at Monday) all commits after Friday's lunch are lost.
Is there another places where i can search for lost commits?
There nothing in git reflog, some dangling commits in git fsck --lost-found, but they are very old and it's nothing helpful there.
Vscode Timeline is also empty, so i have no idea how to recover that commits.
But in PowerShell history i can see all that commits like:
git commit -a -m "Commit 1 text"
git commit -a -m "Commit 2 text"
git commit -a -m "Commit 3 text"


Try git cat-file --batch-check --batch-all-objects | grep commit to list all commits. Check their commit messages.

@ElpieKay Trying to view commit messages, but they are sorted by hash alphabetically, so it's very time consuming:)
btw, i'we using windows, so used findstr instead of grep

Used
git cat-file --batch-check --batch-all-objects | findstr commit > out.txt
and
    $hash = $_.Split(' ')[0]
    git show --no-patch --oneline $hash
}```
To see commits messages and there nothing about commits i've missed
